# Way to export neo 4j graph to rebuild the database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with the neo4j graph database these days for a project and as a precaution, I need to find out that is there a way to export the graph every time I build or make a change in the graph in case an accidental deletion occurs I can rebuild the graph. For example, in MySQL, we can export the database into a SQL script and rebuild the database by running it. What I'm asking is, is there a way in neo4j to do the same thing?

PS:- I use an online sandbox provided by graphenedb.com. Not the one installed locally in the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [export feature](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/importing-and-exporting-databases#section-graphenedb-export). That export file can be used within GrapheneDB to restore it into any other database or to take your data elsewhere.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for.